# is there a way to automatically update proxy object when updating service on WCF?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wcf, visual-studio

i have a WCF web service that i'm working on. currently every time i'm changing the contracts in my service at the server side, i need to both update the service reference and regenerate the proxy object used by the client with "svcutil.exe". is there anyway to do both automatically? i once saw someone who generated the client inside the reference.cs file but i have no idea how he did that. I'm using visual studio 2010.
so far all i have found was different [msdn references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx) telling me to use the svcutil. its not intuitive and usually i can find easier solutions than cmd when working with VS.

Comment: Why do you use both svcutil and a service reference?

Comment: i use the reference to specify the endpoint configuration in my app.config, otherwise it doesn't work. if there is a way to avoid that i would be more than happy to check it out

Comment: And why do you use svcutil? "Add Service Reference" should generate the proxy and the config file changes. You should not need to use svcutil in addition to that.

Comment: allas, it doesn't. it gives me a referrence object which doesnt contain all my operation contracts

Comment: i was actually expecting it to generate it and pretty much surprised when it didn't, that led to 4 hours of debugging and searching the web until i fouind the svcutil which worked

Comment: You should ask a question on why not all of  your contracts are generated. In that question, you should include the svcutil command you're using, and you may need to include some of the WSDL. But if you can't use the service reference, then why do you have one? Just use svcutil alone.

Comment: thanks, i would do it after the weekend, now i'm out of work. from some reason i thought i ought to use proxy. how do i configure the endpoint for the contract in case i wont be able to fix the service reference? although it now sounds a bit illogical, the configuration for the service worked on the proxy as well

Comment: You're using some odd terms. What svcutil produces is meant to be mostly the same as what a service reference produces. In particular, svcutil can also update the config file. See the `/config` and `/mergeConfig` switches of [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Apparently i had to uncheck the reuse types in reference assemblies checkbox, and there was no more difference between the file generated by svcutil and the reference.cs file. I want to blame Microsoft but it really makes sense. Damn. Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 4):

If you want to automate your development work, learn command line and svcutil.exe.

You should use svctuil.exe to generate wsdl and proxy classes which go into a project called something like "MyService.ClientApi". To make thing easier, used a batch file to be called in the build event of the service project.

For more details, please read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627240/WCF-for-the-Real-World-Not-Hello-World

After reading this CodeProject article, you should be able to create respective batch files, and call them in the build events.

And you will see the beauty of separating contracts and implementation into 2 projects.

Say, you will have

- MyServiceContracts.csproj with CreateWsdl.bat to be called in the post build events
- MyServiceImp.csproj
- MyServiceClientApi.csproj with CreateProxy.bat

You can make CreateWsdl.bat call CreateProxy.bat. So everytime you make changes in the contracts, you will have new Wsdl/XSD file to be published, and new MyServiceClientApi.dll to be used by all client programs.

Comment: that is an excellent idea, i haven't used batch files since i was 12 with dos 6. +1. thank you very much. i wont accept it as the answer though since it still require the use of the command line and it feels unmicrosofty. My team members might find it difficult to remember (we have only one wcf module so far). apparently my problem is a bug with the update reference process, i'll know more next week.

Comment: If you haven't used .bat files since 12, I would keep up the good work. Use PowerShell for the same function. Much better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to forgo the use of auto generation, you can construct your service contracts classes manually (go ahead and use reference.cs as a starting point) and then build as a separate assembly that can be shared between the client and server.  Propagation of any later change will then happen automatically as you want whenever the contracts assembly is rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the "Service References" in your Visual Studio project and select "Update service reference". This will update your proxy class and the configuration file.

Comment: well, it doesn't update it from some reason. i can only access the data contracts, not the operation contracts. as mentioned in the above comments, the only thing that did actually work was the svcutil.